# BZIP2 extension for php?

Tags: php

I really don't know how to enable the BZIP2 extension for php.

Anything I'm missing? Because google won't tell me how to.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using 16.04 with php 5.6 installed.

Comment: I assume you're using Ondrej Sury's PPA?

Comment: Yes I am, has been working so far.

Answer (score 4):

> Xenial doesn't ship with PHP 5.x packages, so I am assuming you are using Ondrej Sury's PPA

The `bzip2` plugin is contained in `php5.6-bz2`, and you will need to install it.  Once it is installed, you will need to restart the PHP processor.

If you are using Apache with PHP, and the PHP module that can be embedded in Apache, restart Apache.  If you are using `php5.6-fpm` or similar, restart that service.

The `bzip2` plugin should then be available.

Comment: @BeFreezy glad it helped, feel free to accept it when the system lets you.